# How can I debug a JSONdecode error in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run the following script (using the `capiq-python`) API in Python

```
from capiq.capiq_client import CapIQClient
ciq_client = CapIQClient("EMAIL ADDRESS", "PASSWORD")
data = ciq_client.gdshe(['WMT:', "ibm:"],['IQ_CLOSEPRICE'], ['close_price'], start_date='11/12/2010',end_date='11/18/2010')
print(data)
```

However I keep getting this error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any ideas on how to debug this? There is an actual email address and password in line 2 of my code script, so could the @ sign in my email address be the issue?

TIA

Comment: It most likely has nothing to do with the `@` in your email (what email does **not** have a `@`?). The problem is that in some internal code of either `CapIQClient.__init__` or `gdshe` (impossible to tell since you did not provide the full stacktrace) an API call did not return a valid JSON object. If `capiq-python` is open-source, you are likely to get the most help by opening an issue on the project's repository

Comment: What line of your example is causing the `JSONDecodeError`? Could you add a full stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonCrowe @DeepSpace I'm a bit unsure of how to produce a full stacktrace, I'm running this script through R using a package that's an interface to python (reticulate). But I just ran each line individually and the error is caused by the 3rd line (the ```ciq_client.gdshe``` command).

Comment: Okay, well I think @DeepSpace's suggestion of opening an issue on https://github.com/faaez/capiq-python is reasonable. All I can think of is that it's likely the package is getting a non-JSON response from CapIQ's API.